# Select multiple entities doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to do the following query:

```
$qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
$referredUsers = $qb->select(['referred', 'referral', 'match'])
    ->from('ProjectContestBundle:UserParticipation', 'up')
    ->innerJoin('ProjectUserBundle:User', 'referred', 'WITH', 'up.user = referred')
    ->innerJoin('ProjectUserBundle:User', 'referral', 'WITH', 'up.referral = referral.referralCode')
    ->innerJoin('ProjectContestBundle:UserParticipation', 'upr', 'WITH', 'upr.user = referral')
    ->innerJoin('ProjectMatchBundle:Match', 'match', 'WITH', 'match.owner = referred')
    ->where('up.contest = :contest')->andWhere('upr.contest = :contest')
    ->setParameter('contest', $contest)
    ->getQuery()->getResult();
```

I was expecting as result an array of rows where each row is of type `[User, User, Match]`, Doctrine however returns a plain array with a mixed content of entities.

I've then tried to make it simpler with:

```
$qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
$referredUsers = $qb->select(['referred.id', 'referral.id', 'match.id'])
    ->from('ProjectContestBundle:UserParticipation', 'up')
    ->innerJoin('ProjectUserBundle:User', 'referred', 'WITH', 'up.user = referred')
    ->innerJoin('ProjectUserBundle:User', 'referral', 'WITH', 'up.referral = referral.referralCode')
    ->innerJoin('ProjectContestBundle:UserParticipation', 'upr', 'WITH', 'upr.user = referral')
    ->innerJoin('ProjectMatchBundle:Match', 'match', 'WITH', 'match.owner = referred')
    ->where('up.contest = :contest')->andWhere('upr.contest = :contest')
    ->setParameter('contest', $contest)
    ->getQuery()->getResult();
```

which results in `[{"id":1},{"id":2},{"id":3},{"id":4}]`. If I do run the query on the database it works fine:

```
SELECT u0_.ID AS ID0, u1_.ID AS ID1, m2_.ID AS ID2 FROM UserParticipation u3_ INNER JOIN users u0_ ON (u3_.user_id = u0_.ID) INNER JOIN users u1_ ON (u3_.l = u1_.referralCode) INNER JOIN UserParticipation u4_ ON (u4_.user_id = u1_.ID) INNER JOIN matches m2_ ON (m2_.ownerID = u0_.ID) AND (m2_.deletedAt IS NULL) WHERE u3_.contest_id = 1 AND u4_.contest_id = 1;
```

returns:

```
+-----+-----+-----+
| ID0 | ID1 | ID2 |
+-----+-----+-----+
|   1 |   9 |   1 |
|   1 |   9 |   2 |
|   1 |   9 |   3 |
|  10 |   9 |   4 |
+-----+-----+-----+
```

so I tried to add some `as` and:

```
$referredUsers = $qb->select(['referred.id as r1', 'referral.id as r2', 'match.id as m'])
    ->from('ProjectContestBundle:UserParticipation', 'up')
    ->innerJoin('ProjectUserBundle:User', 'referred', 'WITH', 'up.user = referred')
    ->innerJoin('ProjectUserBundle:User', 'referral', 'WITH', 'up.referral = referral.referralCode')
    ->innerJoin('ProjectContestBundle:UserParticipation', 'upr', 'WITH', 'upr.user = referral')
    ->innerJoin('ProjectMatchBundle:Match', 'match', 'WITH', 'match.owner = referred')
    ->where('up.contest = :contest')->andWhere('upr.contest = :contest')
    ->setParameter('contest', $contest)
    ->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
```

and the result is correct!

```
[{"r1":1,"r2":9,"m":1},{"r1":1,"r2":9,"m":2},{"r1":1,"r2":9,"m":3},{"r1":10,"r2":9,"m":4}]
```

If I try to go back with the non id version, leaving the `as` I still get back an array of rows where each row is a different entity, however I would like to have a row of `[User, User, Match]` as the select shows (the same as the MySql raw result, just with entities).

Comment: Could you put more details about your mapping? I didn't understand it: `referral` and `referralCode` are a columns, but I think should be a relationship userParticipation to user

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Short answer**

doctrines select hydrates objects only as in relationships.

**Long Answer**

Doctrine returns by default the "from entity" as the owner of the query. I mean, it will return a array of this entity and also it will fill the remaining entities inside this entity, according to your mapping.

I suggest you change `up.referral` and `user.referralCode` to be a relationship instead of columns. And another change would be map `User` to access `Match` (if it's an one-to-one relation).

Let's simplify the code a little bit:

```
$qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();

//it will return array of UserParticipation
$userParticipations = $qb->select('up, referred, match')
    ->from('ProjectContestBundle:UserParticipation', 'up')
    ->innerJoin('up.user','referred')
    ->innerJoin('up.referralUser', 'referral')
    ->innerJoin('referred.match', 'match')
    ->where('up.contest = :contest')
    ->setParameter('contest', $contest)
    ->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Each item from `$userParticipations` array gonna be a `UserParticipation`. From it you can access the referred (`$userParticipations[0]->getUser()`), the referral (`$userParticipations[0]->getReferralUser()`), the match (`$userParticipations[0]->getUser()->getMatch()`), and so on.

It's pretty much your first try.

**NOTE** the code above will only works if you do some changes on your mapping and database.

Comment: So that works only when I retrieve entities using relationships in joins? Not just by having entities in the select field?
If so I understood what you meant with the relationship and mapping thing, no need to explain further. In that case it's better to just fetch the corresponding id array and use that directly

Comment: Yes. You understood. Do you just need the ids?

Comment: Well don't just the ids, but adding a couple additional columns would do the trick as I don't really need the full entity, I was just expecting that such select would correctly hydrate all the objects since the select would have all the fields needed to build the entity objects.

Comment: Can you just add a TL;DR part at the beginning of the answer stating that such select hydrates objects only as in relationships?

Comment: You can specify the fields you need. And doctrine only gonna fill/hydrate it. See, [Partial Objects](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/partial-objects.html).

Comment: Yeah I know about partial objects, I'll see if that can work in this case, thanks